# How to get all the tokens ids right after minting?

Tags: tokens, nft, erc-721, mint

I'm currently grabbing the token ID after minting like below.

```
tokenId = BigInt(receipt.logs[0].topics[3]).toString();
```

But if I do bulk minting (say minting 5 NFTs) in one transaction, how do I grab all the IDs?